How to move from Yes to No in toggle switch using selenium java
Here I need to move from Yes to No, so please guide me how to locate XPath for toggle switcher, and please refer below html code
WebElement toggleswitch =wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@id='mfaEnabledId']/following::label[@for='switcher']")));
toggleswitch.click();

I have used this XPath but it throws error like this
FAILED: verifyUserCreaton("naresh", "123", "nareshponnusamy77@gmail.com", "Naresh123", "Naresh@14499", "Naresh@14499")
org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <label for="switcher" style="width: 50%;"></label> is not clickable at point (468, 561). Other element would receive the click: <input type="checkbox" id="mfaEnabledId" style="width: 100%;">
  (Session info: chrome=129.0.6668.101)

HTML
<div class="col-md-6" style="position: relative; top: 5px;">
 <div class="switcher">
  <input type="checkbox" id="mfaEnabledId" style="width: 100%;">
  ::before
  ::after
  </input>
  <label for="switcher" style="width: 50%;">
  </label>
 </div>
</div>


Read your error output "ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element  is not clickable at point (468, 561). Other element would receive the click: "

Clicking the label is giving you the error, but can't you just click the input with the XPath //input[@id='mfaEnabledId'] ?
